# how do I find the index of row in an array that the first column has a specific value and the second column has the max value?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

suppose I have an array `a` with size `(n,2)` like this:

```py
a = np.array([
    [6,   185.153],
    [6,   9.50864],
    [1,   9.31425],
    [1,   16.4629],
    [6,   19.6971],
    [1,   2.02113],
    [1,   14.0193],
    [5,   2.92495],
    [3,   56.0731],
    [3,   77.6965],
])
```

now I need to find the index of row that the first column is specific value `M` (for example 3) and the second corresponding column has max value between other rows with first column equals `M`. for example in the above array the index will be `8` I used the following code but it doese not work and the output is wrong. do you know what is the problem?

```
indx_nonremoved=np.where([minimum_merge.max(axis=1) ==3 ])[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use list comprehensions and the `key` parameter of `max()` built-in function:

```
a=[[6,   185.153],
[6,   9.50864],
[1 ,  9.31425],
[1  , 16.4629],
[6   ,19.6971],
[1   ,2.02113],
[1   ,14.0193],
[5   ,2.92495],
[3   ,56.0731],
[3   ,77.6965]]

print(a.index(max([i for i in a if i[0]==3], key=lambda x : x[1])))
print(numpy.where(a == max([i for i in a if i[0]==3], key=lambda x : x[1]))) #Use this if a is a numpy.ndarray
```

**Output:**

```
9
```

Comment: when I used it, it produces this error:AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'. how can I change my array to list?

Comment: minimum_merge=np.zeros((minimum.shape[0],2))    minimum_merge[0,:]=minimum
        minimum_merge[1,:]=minimum_distance                        minimum_merge.index(max([i for i in minimum_merge if i[0]==H_cluster], key=lambda x : x[1]))

Comment: I have the above code

Comment: @david So `a` is a `numpy.ndarray`?

Comment: yes I said in my quesion. it is an array

Comment: @david Ok, I edited the question with an alternative solution

Comment: the output will be a tuple, right? Do I have to find the index of the tuple that has a non-zero value? but the code will not give the index, right?

Comment: @david Yes, it provides you with the index of the element

Comment: by adding something like this, indx,=np.where(output==1)?

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions are certainly one approach. If you already use numpy, and you have a lot of data, then **`numpy` methods** will be faster...

- I'll make a mask for the first column, to select those rows.
- Then I'll `argsort` just those rows, taking the values from the second column
- finally I'll map the indices from the sorted selection back to the whole array.
- The row containing the maximum is the row with the last index

```py
# a = np.asarray(a)

mask = (a[:,0] == 3)
# array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True])

(indices,) = np.nonzero(mask)
# array([8, 9], dtype=int64)

maxindex = np.argmax(a[mask, 1])
# 1

indices[maxindex]
# 9
```

So row 9 is the best that fits your criteria.

You can reorder the rows of `a` in any way and that will still be true.

The same can be done using `np.argsort` to get all rows sorted, instead of getting just the max.